# how do you assign generic type variable to a know type?

Tags: dart

Consider that I have a two `class` and a `enum`.

one of its class have a parameter as Enum type

```
enum A { B, C }

class Q {
  
  Q(A a);
  
}
```

and Another class is of generic type T which take a one parameter as T type in constructor. **Question is how do you convert this class's parameter type T into A inside of its own class ?**

```
class C<T> {
  
  T a;
  
  C(this.a);
  
  void getType(){
   if(T == A) Q(a); /* The arugument type 'T' can't be assigned to Parameter type 'A'
                     cause Class Type is still 'T' */    
  }
  
}
```

This code contain more than 4 `enum` and each class for its Type. For reproducible purpose, I reduced to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an explicit cast to `A`. Doing a comparison of types like this likely doesn't do implicit type conversion like it would when checking for null in null-safe Dart. Dart isn't able to see that `a` is actually of type `A` even with your `if` statement.

So just do `a as A`.

```
class C<T> {
  
  T a;
  
  C(this.a);
  
  void getType(){
   if(T == A) Q(a as A); 
  }
  
}
```